# Why does set of a pandas dataframe return column names of the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, set

I was just tinkering around and found this amusing:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
>>> x = set(df)
>>> x
{'col2', 'col1'}
```

Why does pandas return column names as set values?

Comment: Same goes for tuple(), list().

Comment: Because iterating directly over a dataframes iterates over it's column names.

Comment: I was just checking out the DataFrame class and was trying to find implementation for `__iter__` method but couldn't find it. I am sorry if this is a stupid question. I am learning.

Comment: It makes a little more sense if you consider that a dataframe is a dict-like container of Series, with column names as keys and series as values. When you iterate over a dict it iterates over the keys

Comment: @Floydian you can find it in it's base class `NDFrame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's how `__iter__` is defined in the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/core/generic.py#L1494) for [`NDFrame`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/core/generic.py#L102), of which [`pd.DataFrame`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/core/frame.py#L248) is a child:

```
def __iter__(self):
    """Iterate over infor axis"""
    return iter(self._info_axis)
```

`pd.DataFrame._info_axis` is used internally to store column labels:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('abcd'))

df._info_axis # Index(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], dtype='object')
```

`set` iterates the `pd.DataFrame` instance via `__iter__`, hashes each element, and returns a `set` of values corresponding to unique column labels.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the implementation for [`__iter__` in `DataFrame`'s parent class `NDFrame`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/362f2e2d8ca42418e65b9c4d20de2ff1bacdabb8/pandas/core/generic.py#L1687):

```
def __iter__(self):
    """Iterate over infor axis"""
    return iter(self._info_axis)
```

It's essentially the same as calling `keys` on a DataFrame, defined in the same location.  I'm including it here because the docstring is more helpful, and describes the differences in `_info_axis` between `Series`, `DataFrame` and `Panel`

```
def keys(self):
    """Get the 'info axis' (see Indexing for more)
    This is index for Series, columns for DataFrame and major_axis for
    Panel.
    """
    return self._info_axis
```